# iOS SDK developer intel & M1 mac simulators

Tags: x86-64, ios-simulator, intel, arm64, apple-silicon

We can use XCFramework to build a new framework that works on both intel based x_86-64 simulators & M1 based arm64 Macs.

Also as many posts online suggest adding arm64 to Excluded Architectures will help resolve build issues. Which is not recommended in long term.

Is there any other way other than using above two ways to add support for both the simulators for a the my SDK I am working?

Note : SDK code is in Objective-C, I am not much aware of it.

Comment: AFAIK excluding arm64 from simulator targets is only necessary if you build iOS and simulator targets at the same time, because Mach-Os can't have two slices for the same architecture.

Comment: I think XCFramework is the only solution